# How to access a function in a stateless component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

Can I access a function in a stateless component? I know that the function can be accessable if change to class component. However, as I know. Hooks is incomptable with class component. Please feel fee to comment. Thank you.

```
# This example is incorrect, for describe the idea only.
const StatelessComponent = () => {

  const StatelessComponentFunction = () => {
    return 1;
  }

}

const thisFun = new TestComponent();

let A = thisFun.StatelessComponentFunction();
```

> **Update on 16, October 2019, solution found.**

Base on the information on these pages "https://hackernoon.com/javascript-state-encapsulation-without-classes-in-2019-97e06c6a9643" and "https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/javascript/closure.html". I found a solution.

Modified

```
const StatelessComponent = () => {

  return {
    StatelessComponentFunction() {
      return 1;
    }
  }

}

const thisFun = StatelessComponent();

console.log(thisFun.StatelessComponentFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

No, a stateless component is used to render jsx to the DOM.

What you have shown isn't really a react component, because it isn't returning jsx. It is just a JS function.

```js
// This example is incorrect, for describe the idea only.
const TestComponent = () => {

  const StatelessComponentFunction = () => {
    return 1;
  }

}

const thisFun = new TestComponent();

let A = thisFun.StatelessComponentFunction();
```

Stateless components should be instantiated like react components `<TestComponent />`

Answer (score 0):

As @Joey_Gough  mentioned. Your component should return JSX whether it is stateful or stateless component.

If you want to execute method in your stateless component then you should create a function inside the Parent `Class Component` and pass that function as a `prop` of Child Component. Something like this:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

  handleClick = () => {
    // Code here
  }

  render() {

    return(
            <StatelessComponent onClicked={handleClick} />
    )
  }
}

const StatelessComponent = (prop) => {

  return(
    <button onClick={prop.onClicked></button> 
  )
}
```